# Xamarin iOS - Firebase Core and Firebase Auth | Error

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**situation:**

I used Xamarin to develop an app for iOS and Android. I recently finished developing the Android application (here everything works with Firebase without any problems).

**problem:**

But when I debug the iOS version on my iPhone SE, the application crashes after lock screen. But when I removed `Xamarin.Firebse.IOS.Core` and `Xamarin.Firebsse.IOS.Auth` everything works fine (of course all processes that do not belong to Firebase).

**console:**

```
Native Crash Reporting
```

---

Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

**IOS NutGet**

[image]

Comment: Does this issue occure on other device version? When you debug, do you get any details on output window or exception?

Comment: Yes, the problem also occurs with other versions of the device(It may also be noted that I am using a physical iPhone, not a virtual one). Here is the debug output: https://justpaste.it/5nepn/pdf

Comment: I just tested the program without using any Xamarin Firebase iOS Core and Xamarin Firebase iOS Auth to start it. So that only the library is installed. There is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[FIX]

Tried every suggestion I could find online e.g. removing and reinstalling Keychain certs.
Ultimately what resolved it was creating a new Provisioning Profile, Downloaded & Installed on mac and using VS's Automatic Provisioning.

Also worth noting for others, I was not aware I needed to attach the phone/device to the mac . I had been attaching it to my windows pc, in my defense this "appeared" to work or be supported by VS.

source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/680747 | 03.08.2021